# Problema al leer un SqlDataReader en Vb .Net

Tags: vb.net

Hola tengo un problema al leer un SqlDataReader en Vb .Net, me da el siguiente mensaje

> Intento no valido de llamar a Read cuando el lector esta cerrado

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ClaseAyuda As New BDCommand
    Dim Sql As String
    Dim Resul As Boolean
    Dim MyReader As SqlDataReader

    'Sql = "Update TBLSALDOSDIARIOS Set PeSecuencia = 1 Where PeFactura = 1024173"
    Sql = "select top 5 PeFactura from TBLSALDOSDIARIOS"


    MyReader = ClaseAyuda.ObtenerData(Sql, My.Settings.SIGMA)

    Try
        While (MyReader.Read)
            MessageBox.Show(MyReader("PeFactura"))
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    MyReader.Close()
End Sub
```

Y en mi clase Ayuda

```
    Public Function ObtenerData(ByVal Sql As String, ByVal Cnn As String) As SqlDataReader
    Dim MyReader As SqlDataReader

    Try
        Dim ActiveCon As New SqlConnection(Cnn)
        Using (ActiveCon)
            ActiveCon.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(Sql, ActiveCon)
            Try
                MyReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            Catch ex As SqlException
                MessageBox.Show("Error al Obtener Datos. " + ex.Message)
                MyReader = Nothing
            End Try
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido un error al ejecutar comando." + ex.Message)
        MyReader = Nothing
    End Try
    Return MyReader
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes devolver un datareader ya que este require que la conexion este abierta, si necesitas devolver datos deberias hacerlo con objetos desconectados como ser un datatable o una lista o coleccion de la clase que definas

Tu codigo deberia ser como esto

```
Public Function ObtenerData(ByVal Sql As String, ByVal Cnn As String) As DataTable

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Try
        Using (ActiveCon As New SqlConnection(Cnn))
            ActiveCon.Open()
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(Sql, ActiveCon)
            da.Fill(dt)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido un error al ejecutar comando." + ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return dt

End Function
```

No es buena practica devolver un `datareader`

---

Sino usa clases y devuelve un objeto tipado, defines una clase (esta forma de definir la propiedad requiere .net 4 o superior)

```
Public Class Factura
    Public Property PeFactura As String
    Public Property PeFechaVencimiento As DateTime
    Public Property PeMontoAs Decimal
End Class
```

Luego la cargas iterando el datareader

```
Public Function ObtenerData(ByVal Sql As String, ByVal Cnn As String) As List(Of Factura)

    Dim list As New List(Of Factura)

    Using (ActiveCon As New SqlConnection(Cnn))
        ActiveCon.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(Sql, ActiveCon)
        Dim MyReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

         While (MyReader.Read)
            Dim item As Factura
            item.PeFactura = MyReader("PeFactura").ToString()
            item.PeFechaVencimiento= Convert.ToDateTime(MyReader("PeFechaVencimiento"))
            item.PeMonto= Convert.ToDecimal(MyReader("PeMonto"))
            lust.Add(item)
        End While

    End Using

    Return list

End Function
```

obtienes la lista de la clase que defines como repsuesta, es similar al datatable solo que con objetos

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Sql As String = "select top 5 PeFactura from TBLSALDOSDIARIOS"

    Dim ClaseAyuda As New BDCommand
    Dim result As List(Of Factura) = ClaseAyuda.ObtenerData(Sql, My.Settings.SIGMA)

    Try

        ForEach item In result
            MessageBox.Show(item.PeFactura)
        End For

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Gracias!! Me parece muy completo el ejemplo utilizando listas. En el caso de obtener mas de un campo como seria ? Ejemplo PeFactura, PeFechaVencimiento, PeMonto

Comment: edite el codigo agregando estas propiedades

Comment: Mil gracias, para mi eso es algo nuevo y me parece muy interesante. Tratare de ver esa clase Factura para implementar métodos Get y Set a ver como va

Answer (score 0):

Debes ejecutar el Reader que has creado mediante la función es por eso que te tira el error.

MyReader = ClaseAyuda.ObtenerData(Sql, My.Settings.SIGMA)

```
Try
    MyReader.ExecuteReader
    While (MyReader.Read)
        MessageBox.Show(MyReader("PeFactura"))
    End While
```

Intenta eso.